# Number padding as a part of string message

Tags: ruby

I would like to have a string like `"The time is #{hours}:#{minutes}"`, so that `hours` and `minutes` is always zero-padded (2 digits). How can I do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use time formatting: [Time#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.new(2012, 12, 12)
t1.strftime "The time is %H:%M" # => "The time is 16:18"
t2.strftime "The time is %H:%M" # => "The time is 00:00"
```

Alternatively, you can use string formatting using the ['%' format operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.new(2012, 12, 12)
"The time is %02d:%02d" % [t1.hour, t1.min] # => "The time is 16:18"
"The time is %02d:%02d" % [t2.hour, t2.min] # => "The time is 00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

See ljust, rjust and center [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html).

Example would be:

`"3".rjust(2, "0") => "03"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the format operator for strings: the `%` operator

```
str = "The time is %02d:%02d" %  [ hours, minutes ]
```

[Reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)

The format string is the same as in the C function printf.

Answer (score 1):

or something like:

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > "The time is %02d:%02d" % [4, 23]
 => "The time is 04:23"
```

Answer (score 1):

sprintf is useful in general.

```
1.9.2-p320 :087 > hour = 1
 => 1 
1.9.2-p320 :088 > min = 2
 => 2 
1.9.2-p320 :092 > "The time is #{sprintf("%02d:%02d", hour, min)}"
 => "The time is 01:02" 
1.9.2-p320 :093 > 

1.9.2-p320 :093 > str1 = 'abc'
1.9.2-p320 :094 > str2 = 'abcdef'
1.9.2-p320 :100 > [str1, str2].each {|e| puts "right align #{sprintf("%6s", e)}"}
right align    abc
right align abcdef
```