# Ruby: How to add zeros to front of a number string using sprintf()

Tags: ruby, string

I want to normalize zipcodes to be 5 digits long with zeros replacing any missing characters like so:

```
"95616" >> "95616"
"854"  >> "00854"
"062" >> "00062"
"0016" >> "00016"
```

I have tried using sprintf like so `sprintf("%05s", zipcode)` and like so 
`sprintf("%0.5d", zipcode)`.  Both give incorrect answers.  Using the `s`:

```
"95616" >> "95616"
"854"   >> "  854"
"062"   >> "  062"
"0016"  >> " 0016"
```

This is the correct number of characters, but using spaces, not zeros.

Using the `d`:

```
"95616" >> "95616"
"854"   >> "00854"
"062"   >> "00050"
"0016"  >> "00014"
```

What is the proper use of sprintf() in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your usage of sprintf is fine. Your problem is that 062 (and 0016) is octal (as is any integer that starts with a 0), and it becomes 50 when converted to base10.

The solution is to get rid of that 0 before it hits your Ruby app. Presuming that it's a string (because your examples show strings), you can do something like this:

```
"062".gsub /^0/, ''
```

And then carry on with the padding and print formatting.

The other way is to *knowingly* print it as an octal if you know it starts with a 0:

```
"%05o" % 062 # => "00062"
```

Of course, if you have control over the input, your best bet is to ensure people can't break your code by inputting numbers you don't expect. eg.

```
"%05s" % 0xff0055 # => 16711765
"%05x" % 0xff0055 # => "ff0055"
```

Checking inputs changes the problem from being a formatting one to a validation one, and it's better to prevent than treat.

(the quirky % syntax is sugar for `printf`/`sprintf`)

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation.  Thanks! (I can't upvote yet, so all I can leave is gratitude)

Answer (score 27):

Don't torture yourself with `sprintf`:

```
puts "123".rjust(5, '0') # => 00123
```

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is, if the number already has leading zeros, they don't get truncated, as they would if the number was converted to an integer and then reformatted. `"000000123".rjust(5, '0') => 
"000000123"` vs. `'%05d' % '000000123'.to_i` => "00123"`.

Comment: @theTinMan This will not likely be an issue. If he has numbers of 6 or more digits, he has got a bigger problem than this.

Comment: I agree, but the reason I mention it is the OP's sample input has various numbers of leading zeros. The samples roam from none to two, so it's conceivable there'd be even more. If the values are coming from user input even wilder things could be received.

Answer (score 6):

You want %05d. Also String#% as a shortcut:

```
"%05d" % "123" #=> 00123
```

Comment: +1 This is how I'd fly. Let Ruby do the conversion from a string to an integer then let `format`... uh... format it.

Comment: This doesn't work with the test case above when the input string contains a leading zero... `"%05d" % "123" => "00123", which does work
"%05d" % "0123" => "00083" which is not "00123"`

Comment: Forcing the string to an integer seems to do the trick
`"%05d" % "0123".to_i => "00123"`

Answer (score 2):

whirlwin's solution seems to me a valid (general padding) solution. Just improve it with max :

```
zipcode.insert 0, '0' * ([5 - zipcode.length, 0].max)
```

To check it :

```
az = ["95616", "854", "062", "0016", '1', '123456']
az.collect {|zipcode| zipcode.insert 0, '0' * (5 - zipcode.length) }

$ ruby -w t.rb
t.rb:2:in `*': negative argument (ArgumentError)
```

Add max to cope with negative values :

```
az = ["95616", "854", "062", "0016", '1', '123456']
az.collect {|zipcode| zipcode.insert 0, '0' * ([5 - zipcode.length, 0].max) }
p az

$ ruby -w t.rb
["95616", "00854", "00062", "00016", "00001", "123456"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While this approach does in fact not use `sprintf`, it should solve your problem in 1 line of code:

```
zipcode.insert 0, '0' * (5 - zipcode.length)
```

Comment: I agree with your solution. I have edited it to add an improvement, but 3 revisers knowing nothing to Ruby rejected it. So I added a new answer.

Comment: Thanks for your editing effort. Yes, my solution does not expect more than 5 a five digit zip code because I've never heard of such a thing...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input everyone.  I was looking to learn more about sprintf and specifically to use sprintf in the solution, and all the ideas were really helpful.  I eventually figured out a bit of a hacky solution to my problem that seems to be flexible and that hasn't been mentioned yet, so I thought I would post it.

As I mentioned, `sprintf("%05s", zipcode)` would return spaces instead of zeros if a number string was not long enough, but it did return the correct number of spaces -- so I just chained a `gsub` to the end to replace the spaces with zeros.

```
sprintf("%05s", zipcode).gsub!(" ", "0")
```

Please let me know if there are any significant problems with this solution.  I have tested it and so far it seems to work.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839519/number-padding-as-a-part-of-string-message/13840077#13840077